Laravel 11 middleware not working it says it doesn't exist
Here is my bootstrap app middleware file:
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;
use App\Http\Middleware\RegistrarMiddleWare;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias(['type.admin' => AdminMiddleware::class]);
        $middleware->alias(['type.registrar' => RegistrarMiddleWare::class]);
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

middleware file
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
      if (request()->user()->tokenCan('role:admin')) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return response()->json('Not Authorized', 401);
    }
}

api file
 Route::post('/employee/register', [AuthController::class, 'EmployeeRegister'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'type.admin']);

error displayed:
"message": "Target class [type.adsssmin] does not exist.",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException",

I tried everything but nothing works
I'm trying to copy this https://medium.com/@slamtm608/laravel-sanctum-multi-authentication-504b9489a2cc but it's not Laravel 11.

Your error says type.adsssmin but you defined type.admin

I copied the wrong error before when I tried new words

Route::post('/employee/register', [AuthController::class, 'EmployeeRegister'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum', AdminMiddleware::class]);If it's like this, it's working.

i fix it doing it like this
$middleware->alias([
'type.registrar' => RegistrarMiddleWare::class,
'type.admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
]);

write the solution as a post and mark it as resolved instead of a comment. So the solution was to pass an array of strings instead of calling the method twice? maybe it is because alias replaces everything instead of adding, so on the second call you were replacing the first alias

I fixed it by doing it like this
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'type.admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
            'type.registrar' => RegistrarMiddleWare::class,
        ]);

    })

